# change tracklist by ajax in sound cloud custom player

Tags: jquery, ajax, soundcloud

I am working on soundcloud custom player example sc-player-standard. I had modified the css as per requirement, but I need to load the new tracks when user goes to particular category . Then in bottom player new category track should be loaded by ajax.

I had use this:

```js
$('div.sc-player, a.sc-player').scPlayer(
    {links: [{url: "http://soundcloud.com/kantmusic/kant-freakish-mind-original", title: "tet"}]}
);
```

But when I am passing url and title as variable, I'm not getting any response and if no. of track url and title  data is too much then response time is very high. Any suggestion?

Link to a demo: 
http://mysharedlink.com/1daytrack

Comment: Here is an option to add a song to the tracklist (not the entire tracklist) hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508821/soundcloud-custom-player-add-and-play-song-dynamically

Comment: thanks raul for ur reply . i have already seen this . but when i am passing track url and title as argument in .scplayer() function then i am not getting any response unfortunately . for example i had stored these thing in variable and when passing this variable then response in none

Answer (score 0):

multiple track url can be added by comma separated. But it increase the player loading time . so i have decided to load single track at a time and on next button and on finish event load next single track . so now player works perfects .